# Programming TFS: How to find out if a particular file exists on the server?

Tags: tfs

How can I programatically find out if a particular file exists on TFS server?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it by using the `ServerItemExists()` method on an instance of a `VersionControlServer`.

```
using (var tfs = TfsTeamProjectCollectionFactory.GetTeamProjectCollection(
    new Uri("http://tfs:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection")))
{
    var server = tfs.GetService<VersionControlServer>();

    Boolean doesFileExist = server.ServerItemExists("$/Project/Main/MySoltuion.sln", ItemType.File);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer myself:
ServerItemExists method
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.teamfoundation.versioncontrol.client.versioncontrolserver.serveritemexists(v=vs.100).aspx
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/pl-PL/vsx/thread/306753e5-8dc4-4f56-9748-9082db3f0c24